Please explain these dataclass functions' definitions... (python)
Sorry, I really don't know how to word this question.
I'm confused about the purpose of the content in the parenthesis after def (e.g (card: str) ) and what the -> symbol is doing. What is going on. And why does one function -> point to the class name and others point to basic data types.
@dataclass
class Card:
    suit: str
    rank: int

def parse_card(card: str) -> Card:
    return Card(card[0], int(card[1:]))



@dataclass
class Rectangle:
    length: int
    width: int

def area(rect: Rectangle) -> int:
    return rect.length * rect.width


@dataclass
class Square:
    color: str
    width: int

@dataclass
class Circle:
    radius: int
    color: str

def square_to_circle(a_square: Square) -> Circle:
    return Circle(a_square.width, a_square.color)


The parse_card function takes one parameter, a string.  It returns a Card object.  Those notations (: str and -> Card) are called "type hinting".  They are ignored by Python, but are used by IDEs and linting tools to check for type problems.

These are type hints.

"I'm confused about the purpose of the content in the parenthesis after def" Are you familiar with standard Python syntax? You seem to have missed a few foundational topics in your learning of the language before moving on to slightly more complex concepts (like classes / dataclasses).

Thanks guys! Im just going to give up though

Strictly speaking, the syntax is called function annotations, which formerly had no defined semantics, but were commonly used for type hints. (Now, they are only used for type hints, or at least in ways that don't conflict with type hinting.)

As mentioned by Tim and Matthias already, these are type hints.
You can read more documentation here: https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/
This is also a duplicate of What does -> mean in Python function definitions?
